# Count Form Submissions on PHP Site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, counter

I would like to implement a counter on a site I am building, so every time someone submits a form on the site, the counter increases for anyone who visits the site. For example, the number will start at 0 and every time someone submits the form, the count will increase for anyone who visits the site.

I know how to manipulate the number via JS/jQuery when the form submission button is clicked. My question is about how to update the number on the site for anyone who visits the site.

The site is currently a static PHP site without a database associated with it.

Comment: clarify `every time someone submits the form, the count will increase for anyone who visits the site` ...the counter is supposed to increase by the number of people who have visited the site everytime the button is pressed...

Comment: You need a database or write the data to a .txt file. Have you tried anything as yet can share with us? , that would expedite the party....

Comment: @andre3wap I haven't tried anything yet. Trying to get ideas to determine the best route to go down. I thought there might be a non-database option.

Comment: @Pamblam — Whenever someone clicks submit on the form, the number count on the site should increase by one. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @Andrew - the answer below might work for ya buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh i get it now..

you can do it with a file.

1) create a file called "counter.txt", put it next to your web page put the number zero in the file.

2) get the current count with php: `$counter = file_get_contents("counter.txt");`

3) add one to the counter `file_put_contents("counter.txt", $counter+1);`

---

```
// put this wherever you want to do your counting
$counter = file_get_contents("counter.txt");
file_put_contents("counter.txt", $counter+1);
echo "You are the $counter person to view this page..";
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that was an option. I'm a little confused how step 3 would work. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Andrew - check the edit. if this helped please be sure to hit the checkmark button :)

Comment: Almost. If I have a form with an action already specified though, can I run the file_put_contents code before the form redirects to the thank you page for the form submission? I guess that is what I am confused about.

Comment: Oh i see. You would just put this on the thank you page.

Comment: just put it at the very top inside the php tags. you can take off the echo too, that was just for demo.